# menu() cannot be used non-interactively in R

Tags: r, unit-testing, testing, devtools

While testing a function when I use `devtools::check()` to build and check the package it throws an error `Error: menu() cannot be used non-interactively`

Below is a small example code.

```
yes <- c("Yes", "Definitely", "Positive", "For sure", "Yup", "Yeah",
         "Absolutely")
no <- c("Not sure", "Not now", "Negative", "No", "Nope", "Absolutely not")

ask_confirmation <- function(title = NULL, positive = yes, negative = no) {
    options <- c(sample(positive, 1), sample(negative, 2)) # Mix which ones
    options <- sample(options, 3) # Random order
    sel <- menu(options, title = title)
    invisible(c("Cancel", options)[sel + 1])
}
```

How to overcome this problem? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your are testing your own package. If so, you can put the offending examples (that call `menu()`) in a `\donttest{ }` block.

See [Writing R Extensions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Documenting-functions)

Comment: `\donttest { }` is used in documentation. I assume this is not the answer I'm looking for. FYI, added an example for your reference. Thank You:)

Comment: Yes, it is in the documentation. That (under `\examples{}`) is where I would expect that `ask_confirmation`  is called (and nowhere else).

Comment: I'm using `ask_conferamtion` in my package and I'm calling in other functions too. So I'm not sure how can I put my function under `\examples{ }`.

Comment: You can use `\examples{\donttest{  examples here } }` in all examples, or any that (indirectly) call `ask.confirmation`.

Comment: And this is what is done for `?menu`  itself

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if it would work in non-interactive environments but maybe the `usethis::ui_line` function would work? If it does I'll make it an answer.